# Reindexing rows by reversed column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this `df`, where inverted column values are far apart from each other, like so:

```
            Team     Adversary      Home  
0   Internacional   Bahia           Home
1        Flamengo   Grêmio          Home     
... 
18         Grêmio   Flamengo        Away
19          Bahia   Internacional   Away
```

---

For every

```
tuple1 = ('Team', 'Adversary') and tuple2 = ('Adversary', 'Team')
```

where

```
tuple1[0] == tuple2[0] and tuple1[1] == tuple2[1]
```

how do I reorder the rows, ending up with:

```
            Team     Adversary      Home  
0   Internacional    Bahia          Home                          
1          Bahia     Internacional  Away 
2        Flamengo    Grêmio         Home                          
3          Grêmio    Flamengo       Away 
...
```

Comment: Please explain better how do you want to reorder the rows

Comment: @gtomer is it clearer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.sort` to sort the values of `Team` and `Adversary` along `axis=1`, then using `sort_values` sort the dataframe based on this sorted columns `x` and `y`:

```
df['x'], df['y'] = np.sort(df[['Team', 'Adversary']], axis=1).T
df = df.sort_values(['x', 'y'], ignore_index=True).drop(['x', 'y'], 1)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

            Team      Adversary  Home
0  Internacional          Bahia  Home
1          Bahia  Internacional  Away
2       Flamengo         Grêmio  Home
3         Grêmio       Flamengo  Away
```

Comment: `KeyError: "None of [Index(['x', 'y'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

Comment: Which pandas version are you using?

Comment: `pandas   0.25.3`

Comment: Hmm..that;s why you are getting error because multiple column assignment is not supported in version `0.25`..let me edit the solution..

Comment: @8-BitBorges please check now.

Comment: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`, my dtaframe has many other columns...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220982/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-8-bit-borges).

Answer (score 0):

You confused me there for a second by using the word 'grouping'.

The easiest way to do this is to use the fact that combining teams names from Team and Adversary column have the same set of letter.

```
df.combo=df.Team+df.Adversary
df.combo=["".join(sorted(list(i)) for i in df.combo]
```

what this does -for example- is make sure that the combination of "Internacional" and "Bahia" is always `['B', 'I', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'l', 'n', 'n', 'o', 'r', 't']` or 'BIaaaacehiilnnort' no matter which ones occurs first.
Essentially you are using the unique letters content of the sorted letters combination as a unique id.

Now sort using the combo column

```
df = df.sort_values(by="combo", ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

finally drop the combo column

```
df = df.drop(["combo"], axis=1)
```